# C - WinAPI GetLastError returns 3

Tags: winapi

The GetLastError function returns error code 3, which explains that the path specified cannot be found. Why? Is there a specific way of specifying path files with WinAPI? I know the path file is correct, because I copy pasted it.

```
char tDirectory[] = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe"; 

    if (!CreateProcess(tDirectory, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) {

        printf("Error creating process, with error code: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;

    }

    printf("Process created...");

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: may be in system where you run not exist such path. may be windows installed not in *c:*. need not hardcode path but detect it in runtime

Comment: CreateProcess is defined as CreateProcessW per default. You should either use TCHAR or CreateProcessA.

Answer (score 2):

Is your app 32 bit?  If so, you have likely fallen foul of Windows' [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog64/file-system-redirector), which gives 32 bit apps a filtered view of the file system for certain directories.

To get round this, you can do:

```
void *was;
Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection (&was);
CreateProcess (...);
Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection (was);
```

And that should fix it.

Comment: No way redirection leads to that error. Also, disabling redirection is very risky thing to do. Don't recommend that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You're right - error 3 means path not found and that cannot be the case here.  Disabling the file system redirector has its uses however as it allows a 32 bit app to launch a 64 bit app from the (real) system32 directory.

Comment: Which is better done using sysnative. If you ever do need to disable redirection, do it for the calling thread only.

Answer (score -1):

```
CreateProcessA
```

Fixed my code, thanks everyone.

Comment: I guess that's what compiler warnings are for.

Comment: If the code shown actually compiled withoit error then it means `CreateProcess()` already mapped to `CreateProcessA()`, so this could not have been the solution.

Comment: @Michael Maybe compiling as C, rather than C++